# How do I keep the WebBrowser control from catching exceptions and displaying them as script errors?

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, webbrowser-control

I have a rather complicated set of interactions going on between my C# application and an embedded `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` control using the `ObjectForScripting` property. Unfortunately, I've made a mistake somewhere that's causing an exception. But I can't see any information other than the message because the control appears to catch all exceptions that occur in native methods invoked from Javascript and display them as script errors.

Is there any way to disable this behavior so exceptions will be thrown as they normally would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't end up with a universal solution, but this one works well enough for me.

Communication between the browser and my application is only done through a single Javascript method. So I just wrapped all of the code in that method in a try/catch block and threw the exception on another thread.

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class JavascriptBridge {
    public void Notify(string data) {
        try {
            // Process the data
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) => {
                throw new Exception("An unhandled exception ocurred while servicing a Javascript method call.", ex);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This completely bypasses the browser control's exception handler and retains the original exception's location information. Note, however, that the only way to catch the exception again is with the `Application.ThreadException` event.